# How to define Product Category and aggregates each Products sale?

Tags: mysql, sql

My excel sheet has various Products, ship to date,year, Invoice, Amount.
Firstly, How can I define category of Products under one category  in SQL ?
EG:

```
Product Line | Product Type | Ship To Week | Year | Amount
Eye Lasher   | EYE MAKEUP   |  12          | 2017 | 45
Mascara      | EYE MAKEUP   |  27          | 2017 | 23
Lipstick     | LIP MAKEUP   |  13          | 2019 | 28
Hair Oil     | HAIR MAKEUP  |  11          | 2019 | 27
Lip Liner    | LIP MAKEUP   |  52          | 2018 | 19
Night Cream  | Face MAKEUP  |  13          | 2019 | 28
```

How can I define various Products into different category and each product type aggregates in SQL? Therefore my o/p shall be : Eye Makeup Total sale in 2017 =68

Comment: You should read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-functions-and-modifiers.html

Answer (score 1):

Are you just looking for aggregation?

```
SELECT Year, Product_Type, SUM(Amount)
FROM mytable
GROUP BY Year, Product_Type
```

Comment: I tried the code above, it works fine. But I see my Input has data of 21 K rows, but output is only 106 rows. It means its not considering all rows ?